# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Yii2 popup form

Tags: forms, yii2, popup, yii2-model

I have a problem with a pop-up form in Yii2. "Update" is not working. The form is displayed but inspect tool shows:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

The action of creating uses the same code and it works perfectly. I do not know what's going on.

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('click','#modalButton',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('value');

    $.get('update',{'id':id},function(data){
        $('#modalUpdate').modal('show')
        .find('#modalContentUpdate')
        .html(data);
    });

});
```

[This is my index.php](http://ideone.com/xA3rDL)

Comment: use $.post instead of $.get.. nd then try... hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit.

This is almost always because of a recursive function with a base case that isn't being met.

**Viewing the stack**

Consider this code...

```
(function a() {
    a();
})();
```

The call stack grows until it hits a limit: the browser hardcoded stack size or memory exhaustion.

In order to fix it, ensure that your recursive function has a base case which is able to be met...

```
(function a(x) {
    // The following condition 
    // is the base case.
    if ( ! x) {
        return;
    }
    a(--x);
})(10);
```